# clamav can't find viruses in rar files on centos 6.4

Tags: centos, centos6, clamav, centos6.4, rar

I use ClamAV 0.97.8/17494 on CentOS 6.4. It's good but can't find viruses in rar files. It can detect same virus file as it is or in a zip file but in rar file ClamAV reports no virus.

`ScanArchive=yes` option is already enabled

I searched a lot on google but couldn't find a solution.

Does anyone know if there is a fix for this?

### EDIT 1

Package unrar-4.2.3-1.el6.rf.i686 already installed and latest version

### EDIT 2

ClamAV was installed using `yum install clamav clamd`

```
#ldd $(which clamscan)
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x008fb000)
libclamav.so.6 => /usr/lib/libclamav.so.6 (0x0051a000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00ddc000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x002d3000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x00490000)
libbz2.so.1 => /lib/libbz2.so.1 (0x00dc3000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x004a6000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00489000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x002ad000)
```

Comment: Was this installed from RPM or built from source? Can you `ldd $(which clamscan)` and check for missing libraries? (Show up in bold.)

Comment: @AaronCopley I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Do you have unrar installed?  It isn't part of the standard Centos Repos.  Installation instructions are available [online](http://google.com/?q=unrar%20centos%206).

Comment: yes it's installed

Comment: [ClamAV claims internal support for RAR](http://www.clamav.net/doc/latest/clamdoc.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Most distributions exclude rar 3.0 support from ClamAV packages as the ClamAv authors had no legal right to include it. If you want rar support in ClamAV then you need to build it from the unmodified source which can be downloaded from the ClamAV website.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was about CentOS, but I had the same problem on Debian. Here, you need to install a separate package that contains the unrar library to make ClamAV support rar:

```
# Debian Stretch:
apt install libclamunrar7

# Debian Buster:
apt install libclamunrar9
```

This requires the `non-free` repository, as rar is proprietary software.

Answer (score -1):

Had this problem. Upgraded to 0.97.7, no problem with it now, it can find the virus in the RAR files.